# Multi-threading with Discord (scheduled job)

Tags: python, python-asyncio, discord, discord.py

Firstly, an apology. I'm pretty new to Python. I come from a Java/C# coding background. I'm loving Pythons simplicity in many ways, but also finding some standards hard to pin down.

For instance, I've successfully managed to get a Discord Bot running. The async methods are working well. But I would like to schedule a job to run every (say) 30 minutes. However, when I type asyncio.run(job()), Python tells me that "run" is not an attribute of asyncio. I'm really not sure why it would say that. Heck, is asyncio even the "right" way to do this?

Is it possible the discord import has masked it in some way? I think I might need to get a book or something!

Again, thanks. I did try a search on this, but nothing came up!

Comment: Asycio is not easy to start with. I recommend you to read [this guide](https://pymotw.com/3/asyncio/) first.

Comment: Ah, so maybe I see my problem. I need to get an "event_loop", and "run" against that. Will "run_forever" run in the background and continue with the next command? Or will it just block? I can add a "sleep" in my code if that frees it up.

Comment: You should add some code, so we can see what you're attempting.

Comment: `asyncio.run` is not the right way to do this as `client.run` already starts an event loop in `discord.py` -- there can only be one event loop at once!

Comment: `run` might not be an attribute of `asyncio` as it was only added in Python 3.7 -- which Python version do you "run"? :-)

Comment: what python version are you using? asyncio.run works only on python after 3.7+

Answer (score 6):

`on_ready` is called when the discord bot gets initiated so one way is to attach your job to it:

```
import discord
import asyncio

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(30*60)  # every 30 minutes
        job()

client.run(os.environ.get('DISCORD_BOT_SECRET'))  # provide your API token here!!
```

`asyncio.sleep` is a *non-blocking* sleep -- if one were to use `time.sleep` here, then the bot would wait for `time.sleep` to complete and would be unresponsive to any other messages coming in. But what `await asyncio.sleep` does is yield control back to the event loop which can take care of other bot functions. Only after 30 minutes control will return to `on_ready`.

Note that **while your job runs it will block your bot** which is a problem for jobs tasking longer than a few seconds. If your job is I/O-based (e.g. fetching websites) you can use async I/O operations (such as aiohttp) to keep it responsive. If your job is CPU-based you might have to use multiple processes, such as `subprocess.Popen` if your job can be invoked with a terminal command.

Comment: For multiple jobs: Create each job as `async def` function (including `while True` loop) and launch each of them as task once in `on_ready`!

Answer (score 1):

The **modern** way to schedule a job every 30 minutes is using [**`discord.ext.tasks`**](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/):

```
import asyncio
import contextlib
import discord
from discord.ext import tasks

client = discord.Client()

@tasks.loop(minutes=30)  # every 30 minutes
async def job():
    with contextlib.suppress(Exception):
        ...  # your code here

job.start()
client.run(os.environ.get('DISCORD_BOT_SECRET'))  # provide your API token here!!
```

The function `job()` will be called every 30 minutes by the Discord client's event loop. A couple notes here:

- **If `job()` throws an exception, the ENTIRE LOOP will stop.** That is right, not just this invocation, but the entire loop will exit. That is why I added a with-statement to catch all exceptions, this is equivalent to `try: ...  except: pass`.
- **While `job()` is running, the other parts of your bot are blocked.** This is because async is not implemented using multiple threads but using coroutines in a single thread. A way around this could be to make your code async (e.g. using `aiohttp` for web requests) or to start another process using `subprocess.Popen`.